# How to check if Azure agent is installed and running on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-pipelines, windows-server

How to check if an Azure agent is installed and running on a windows machine? The operating system of Windows machine is Windows Server 2016. I know the name of the Azure agent. It is an agent for a Pipeline.

Comment: Can you add more context on which agent are you referring to here? Or add some images or commands in your question for me to understand better?

Comment: There are many agents, Example Azure monitoriing agent, There are agents for custom script extensions too

Answer (score 0):

Locate the C:\WindowsAzure folder. If you see the GuestAgent folder that displays the version number, that means that Azure VM Agent was installed on the VM